# What could I use to recover lost/damaged files from a Mac hard drive?

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive, data-recovery

We frequently use the software GetDataBack (for FAT32 and for NTFS) to recover overwritten or lost files, sometimes from a faulty hard drive.

But is there something like this for Mac hard drives? Because we have an external drive here that has been used for Time Machine, but something went wrong and some files were overwritten. We'd like to get those back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disk Drill](http://www.cleverfiles.com/) seems to be the way to go. This piece of software was able to recover a bunch of files that got overwritten bij other Time Capsule backups. Unfortunately, it doesn't recover the original file names but instead gives everything a generic name like file0001.jpg, file0002.png,... It also doesn't find any original folder structures. But at least it's something.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the damage, you might consider [Spinrite](http://www.grc.com).

It is $90, but I believe that there is a 30-day money-back guarantee.

It is a DOS program on a bootable CD, which may or may not work on a MAC (you may have to pull the drive). If Spinrite doesn't work, you could always ask for a refund.